# How do I refer to http resources on a https page safely?

Tags: asp.net, http, https

I have enabled HTTPS for my site. Some of the resources such as css and js files on my pages come from another domain which is on HTTP. Now the problem is when I visit the page, browsers display an alert message. IE says "Do you want to view only the page content that was delivered securely" and FF says "You have requested an encrypted page that contains some unencrypted information. Information that you see or enter on this page could easily be read by a third party."

I tried the [technique mentioned by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) which is not working.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

I use asp.net 3.5 for my site.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue any work arround you found for that?

Answer (score 2):

The assumption he makes in the referenced article I think you missed is

> … assuming the site you're pointing to has this asset available on
>   both HTTP and HTTPS.

Those resources need to be served over HTTPS as well, or you will always get that message. I don't believe there is a way around it, and there likely shouldn't be a way around it. You want everything running over HTTPS for a reason.

Comment: No, there's no way around it. HTTPS pages must use only HTTPS resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve those resources over HTTPS.

The Firefox [Mixed Content Blocking Announcement](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/) does a good job explaining the security risks.

Answer (score 0):

If you own/control the other website where the resource files are located, a good solution might be to move the resource files over to the website where both HTTP and HTTPS are supported, and change both websites to point to those files at their new location.